# Accessing an array of memory addresses

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I've been programming simple things in C, and now i found something a bit more complicated.

This program for PVSNESLIB takes pattern, palettes and maps names from images defined in asm:

```
patterns:
.incbin "RES/images/bkg1.pic" 
patterns_end:
patterns1:
.incbin "RES/images/bkg2.pic" 
patterns1_end:
palette:
.incbin "RES/images/bkg1.pal"
palette_end:
palette1:
.incbin "RES/images/bkg2.pal"
palette1_end:
map:
.incbin "RES/images/bkg1.map"
map_end:
map1:
.incbin "RES/images/bkg2.map"
map1_end:
;;; and so on...
```

And shows them on screen using these sample functions:

```
bgInitTileSet(0, &patterns, &palette, 0, (&patterns_end - &patterns), 256*2, BG_256COLORS, 0x0000);
bgInitMapSet(0, &map, (&map_end - &map),SC_32x32, 0x2000);
   v++; 
//&patterns_end - &patterns is the patterns size
//&map_end - &map is the map size
//0x0000 & 0x2000 are a vram addresses
```

The next code will show a "movie":

```
//char defined in external asm file 
extern char patterns, patterns_end, patterns1, patterns1_end,.......;
extern char palette, palette1,.......;
extern char map, map_end, map1, map1_end,.......;

//now store all addresses inside arrays (is this wrong?)
char *PAT[] = {&patterns,&patterns_end,&patterns1,&patterns1_end,.......};
char *PAL[] = {&palette,&palette_end,&palette1,&palette1_end,.......};
char *MAP[] = {&map,&map_end,&map1,&map1_end,.......};

//now access addresses to use in a function
int main(){
  while(1){   
   bgInitTileSet(0, PAT[v], PAL[v], 0, (PAT[v+1] - PAT[v]), 256*2, BG_256COLORS, 0xC000);
   bgInitMapSet(0, MAP[v], (MAP[v+1] - MAP[v]),SC_32x32, 0x7000);
   v++; 
   WaitForVBlank();
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `patterns1`?

Comment: The first element of `PAT` is `PAT[0]`.

Comment: patternsX, patternsX_end, (being X = 1,2,3,4...) are arrays of tiles from converted images for the SNES.

Comment: But you haven't declared them in your code sample.

Comment: That code is just a part of a big c, I did not write all of it.

Comment: Show enough of it so that it makes sense -- if you have `&patterns1`, show its declaration too.

Comment: There it is, much more complete.

Comment: Your first code snippet is correct. Perhaps the problem is that the definitions in the ASM file do not match the definitions in the C file. It would be good if you could post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including both the C code and the ASM code.

Comment: If `bgInitTileSet` is the SNES function of that name, then you are using it incorrectly. The second argument needs to be a pointer to a tile set (which consists of many characters) however you are passing a pointer to a single character.

Answer (score 0):

Look, patterns is just a char, it is not an array. And patterns_end is just a char too. So you only have two chars, not a succesion of chars.
You can do a for loop, defining a pointer to patterns, and then adding 1 until the address of this aux pointer matches patterns_end address.
Something like this:

```
char *aux = &patterns;
char *pattern_vector;
int i;

for(i=0; aux!= (&patterns_end) ; i++) {
  pattern_vector[i] = aux;
  aux++;  // Look that here, i am incrementing the address value
}

//Then, here you can use your array
```

See if it works. If I made no mistake (I did it quickly), it should!

Comment: Thanks, I don't know if i made myself clear, so i posted a more complete code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Very sorry, writing the complete code i realized i was using the wrong number in PAT[v].

At least i learned something:

```
char *PAT0 = &patterns; 
char *PAT[] = {&patterns,.......};
```

"PAT0" and "PAT[0]" will hold the same (correct) address.

Thanks everybody.